# Action of Custom Show set by VBA code but it says "The custom show "" doesn't exist"

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm using the code to do the following things; 
1. Get the Current Slide index 
2. Go To specific slideshow 
3. Change the Action of a shape to go on the specific slideshow (means back to previous, but I don't want to use ppPreviousSlide action)

Everything works fine but when I clicked the shape of which I change the Action Interaction, It says *"The Custom show doesn't exist"*

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJlwO.jpg)

```
Sub gotoTomatoVariety()
Dim tomatoSlide As Integer: tomatoSlide = 63
Set tableSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex)
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide (tomatoSlide)

With ActivePresentation.Slides(tomatoSlide).Shapes("Go Back") _
    .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionNamedSlideShow
    .SlideShowName = "Slide59"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
.Action = ppActionNamedSlideShow
```

with this:

```
With.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
  .Action = ppActionNamedSlideShow
  .SlideShowName = "name of your custom show"
End With ' action settings
```

Comment: I did add `.SlideShowName = "name of your custom show"` but still getting same error. Also, one thing to note, `.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)` is with the above line, followed by _Underscore_, it will produce an error if I add `with`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "followed by underscore", but the code I suggested works as expected here. Please try it w/o making changes to it (other than providing the name of an actual custom show in place of "name of your custom show"; the name of your show must also be in quotes)

Comment: To breakdown the line of code, we add **_ _THE Underscore symbol_** at the end of the previous line and continue writing code in the next line, so it will be considered the part of the previous line...

Comment: *slaps self on forehead* Sorry, of course. The code I posted should work/does work here if you remove the underscore.

Comment: Everything works fine BUT, it sets the action but doesn't sets the `SlideShowName`...

Comment: Can you edit your original post to show the current code you're working with?  That might help

Comment: What happens if you enter this into the Immediate window with your presentation open:  ? activepresentation.SlideShowSettings.NamedSlideShows("Slide59").Count